# Prevent brute force with php

Tags: php, html

I have a php script and would like to add protection against brute force, can anyone help? I don't want a captcha, but something in which the client is prevented from making further attempts for a certain time after several failed login attempts. And if possible without a database.

Another question by the way, how can you keep a log of all log in (attempts) and from which ip address they come from?

```
<?php

$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
  'Admin' => 'Password',
);

define('USE_USERNAME', true);

define('LOGOUT_URL', 'https://example.com');

define('TIMEOUT_MINUTES', 1);

define('TIMEOUT_CHECK_ACTIVITY', true);

if(isset($_GET['help'])) {
  die('Include following code into every page you would like to protect, at the very beginning (first line):<br>&lt;?php include("' . str_replace('\\','\\\\',__FILE__) . '"); ?&gt;');
}

$timeout = (TIMEOUT_MINUTES == 0 ? 0 : time() + TIMEOUT_MINUTES * 60);

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  setcookie("verify", '', $timeout, '/'); // clear password;
  header('Location: ' . LOGOUT_URL);
  exit();
}

if(!function_exists('showLoginPasswordProtect')) {

function showLoginPasswordProtect($error_msg) {
?>

<!-- ↓ Log in form ↓ -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <p id="errormsg"><?php echo $error_msg; ?></p>
    <input type="hidden" id="harvestID" value="none" />
    <input type="hidden" id="expiryID" value="none" />
    <input type="hidden" id="authenticationID" value="true" />
    <form id="command" name="form2" action="/" method="post">
        <input id="iForgotNewWindowVar" name="openiForgotInNewWindow" type="hidden" value="false" value="false"/>
        <input id="fdcBrowserData" name="fdcBrowserData" type="hidden" value=""/>
        <div class="pair">
            <div class="module">
                <label for="accountname">Name</label>
                <input id="access_login" name="access_login" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" autocapitalize="off" aria-label="Name" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div class="module">
                <input id="access_password" name="access_password" autocorrect="off" oncopy="return false;" oncut="return false;" autocapitalize="off" type="password" value="" size="30" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
  // stop at this point
  die();
}
}

if (isset($_POST['access_password'])) {

  $login = isset($_POST['access_login']) ? $_POST['access_login'] : '';
  $pass = $_POST['access_password'];
  if (!USE_USERNAME && !in_array($pass, $LOGIN_INFORMATION)
  || (USE_USERNAME && ( !array_key_exists($login, $LOGIN_INFORMATION) || $LOGIN_INFORMATION[$login] != $pass ) )
  ) {
    showLoginPasswordProtect("Failed to log in, try again");
  }
  else {
    setcookie("verify", md5($login.'%'.$pass), $timeout, '/');
    
    unset($_POST['access_login']);
    unset($_POST['access_password']);
    unset($_POST['Submit']);
  }

}

else {

  if (!isset($_COOKIE['verify'])) {
    showLoginPasswordProtect("");
  }

  $found = false;
  foreach($LOGIN_INFORMATION as $key=>$val) {
    $lp = (USE_USERNAME ? $key : '') .'%'.$val;
    if ($_COOKIE['verify'] == md5($lp)) {
      $found = true;
      if (TIMEOUT_CHECK_ACTIVITY) {
        setcookie("verify", md5($lp), $timeout, '/');
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!$found) {
    showLoginPasswordProtect("");
  }

}

?>

CONTENT HERE WILL BE DISPLAYED AFTER LOGIN
```

Comment: Why don't you want a captcha, specifically? You can get ones now which don't necessarily require user interaction

Comment: Because I don't want to have scripts from external providers like google etc.

Comment: You have to first decide how robust/smart the firewall has to be. Do you want it to catch distributed humanly timed requests, that for instance may also spoof their user agent? Or will a simple IP-based rate limit suffice? Something in between? Set a goal first.

Comment: First, please keep it to one question per post. Second, when posting code, members here are usually looking to help fix a problem with existing code, not just write new code for someone. Right now all we see is "I found some [code](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/password-protect.php) written 20 years ago that does X and I want it to do Y, too". If you are able to actually try to do something, with some code that you've written, we're much more likely to help you.

Comment: Doing this at application level isn't necessary. I use fail2ban for this, which works off the Apache it Nginx log files and so won't involve PHP at all

Comment: why are external scripts a problem? P.S. this login code in your question is hopelessly out of date. md5 has been crackable for years - making you doubly vulnerable to brute force attacks. And you should never be putting the user's password into a cookie, whether hashed or not. P.P.S. The last comment above is correct - if you want IP based blocking/limiting (which is probably what you'll end up with if you don't want to use captcha to protect a specific form) this is really something you'd do at the server level.

Comment: I log the attempts in a table with a timestamp, the attempted username and password and the user's ip. Once they have tried 3 times unsuccesfully within a minute I ban the user from attempting another login for 10 minutes.